# how do i convert IEnumerable<MyClass> to DataTable very fast?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, datatable, anonymous-types

I'm familiar with the reflection method that converts any IEnumerable to DataTable, but it's very very slow!
When i get  not huge but big chunk of data i get very slow browser reaction, because it's very complicated data to handle.

I need to boost my prefformance, how do i do it? 
PS: Checked LazyLoading DataTable no success there ether, maybe someone will show me how to do it?

Thank you very very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dal/archive/2009/04/08/how-to-convert-an-ienumerable-to-a-datatable-in-the-same-way-as-we-use-tolist-or-toarray.aspx) artice for detailed explanation.

Core code sample

```
 public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        Type t = typeof(T);
        PropertyInfo[] pia = t.GetProperties();
        //Create the columns in the DataTable
        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in pia)
        {
            if ((pi.PropertyType.IsGenericType) )
            {
                Type typeOfColumn = pi.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                dt.Columns.Add(pi.Name, typeOfColumn);
            }
            else
                dt.Columns.Add(pi.Name, pi.PropertyType);
        }
        //Populate the table
        foreach (T item in collection)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr.BeginEdit();
            foreach (PropertyInfo pi in pia)
            {
                dr[pi.Name] = pi.GetValue(item, null);
            }
            dr.EndEdit();
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        return dt;
    }
}
```

Why do you think that data converting slows your app? Did your profile it?

Comment: This won't work for me cause like I've said I receive the IEnumerable as an anonymous cause I have to filter my result, it's an old code I have to upgrade.

Comment: And one more thing, this method doesn't support Nullable<>, i would have to change it to get nullable.

Comment: I had to modify the code slightly to work with my WPF application, however perfect answer